# BS4 Beautiful Soup extract text from find_all

Tags: beautifulsoup

I am scraping a website and would like to create a list of prices.

```
prices = soup.find_all("li", class_="price")
```

However, this returns:

```
 <li class="price">€13.99</li>, 
 <li class="price">€12.99</li>, 
.....
```

How do I extract just the price? I tried

```
prices = soup.find_all("li", class_="price", text=True)
```

but it did not work.

I know I can go through the list manually and extract the text but this isn't ideal.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming content is not dynamically added, which it appears it is not, I would use `.text` to extract from elements returned by using `select`

```
prices = [item.text for item in soup.select('li.price')]
```

Answer (score 1):

`find_all()` returns list of element.You need to iterate this to get each `element` and then get the `text` of the element.

```
prices = soup.find_all("li", class_="price", text=True)
for price in prices:
  print(price.text)
```