# Extract text with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to learn how to use beautiful soup

using this website as a very simple example.
https://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/ground/56490.html#Profile

Lets say I want to extract the capacity of the ground. I have so far written the following code which gives me the field names, but I can't seem to understand how to get the actual value of 18,000

Can anyone help?

```
url="https://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/ground/56490.html"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)
soup.findAll('label')
```

Comment: This might be useful: https://matix.io/extract-text-from-webpage-using-beautifulsoup-and-python/

Comment: Also try adding argument ```features= 'html.parser'``` to you BeautifulSoup constructor

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BS4 Beautiful Soup extract text from find\_all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56860559/bs4-beautiful-soup-extract-text-from-find-all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/ground/56490.html"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
stats = soup.find('div', {'id': 'stats'})
for e in stats.findAll('label'):
    print(f"{e.text}: {e.nextSibling}")
```

[demo](https://repl.it/repls/LightgreyBlindAnimatronics)