# Beautiful Soup - extracting text from multiple webpages using find_all

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the 'All Ages' vote counts from some IMDb ratings pages, but the code I have written returns additional HTML code and I am unsure of how to just extract the number only. IMDb had some data available to download, but not counts for Male and Female voters. I have read through and tried solutions listed in similar SO questions, like [BS4 Beautiful Soup extract text from find_all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56860559/bs4-beautiful-soup-extract-text-from-find-all) but using .text or text=True returns nothing.

The code I am using:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import get
from operator import itemgetter

imdburls = ['https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0029844/ratings','https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0030993/ratings']

Votes = []

for i in imdburls:
    url = i
    page = get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml') 
    content = soup.find(id="main")
    voteValues = content.find_all(class_="smallcell")
    voteValues = itemgetter(0,5,10)(voteValues) # This returns the values from the 'All Ages' column
    Votes.append(voteValues)
```

Votes returns this for the first url, when I just want the actual number:

```
[(<div class="smallcell">
  <a href="/title/tt0029844/ratings?demo=imdb_users">
                      1,761
                  </a>
  </div>,
  <div class="smallcell">
  <a href="/title/tt0029844/ratings?demo=males">
                      1,176
                  </a>
  </div>,
  <div class="smallcell">
  <a href="/title/tt0029844/ratings?demo=females">
                      178
                  </a>
  </div>),
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `.text` of the `<a>` elements within the `<div>`s.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import get
from operator import itemgetter

imdburls = ['https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0029844/ratings','https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0030993/ratings']

Votes = []

for i in imdburls:
    url = i
    page = get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml') 
    content = soup.find(id="main")
    voteValues = content.select("div.smallcell > a")
    voteValues = itemgetter(0,5,10)(voteValues) # This returns the values from the 'All Ages' column
    Votes.append([n.text.strip() for n in voteValues])

from pprint import pprint
pprint(Votes)
```